Need to Flush() before Seek() on a FileStream?
I'm writing a data storage library that writes records to specific positions in a binary file. For each written record, its byte position in the file is determined, the file stream is seeked to that position and then the record bytes are written.
Now I'm observing strange behaviour where other data is written than passed to the write call. Some records are just duplicated (overwrites adjacent record), others are plain garbage when reading again. The bug occurs very rarely but still damages some data every now and then which is unacceptable. Maybe it's my seeking and flushing that's not correct here. Since buffer/flush issues are not reproducible by nature, I can't write a test case to identify the issue (yet).
The code goes like this:
// Init
var file = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.CreateNew);
var writer = new BinaryWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8, leaveOpen: true);

// For each record to write, in random order
long index = GetIndex(record.Time);
long newPosition = headerLength + index * recordLength;
file.Seek(newPosition, SeekOrigin.Begin);
writer.Write((byte)record.Flags);
writer.Write((double)record.Value);

// Closing
writer.Close();
file.Close();

So I do a seek for each record, but no flush. I want to keep disk write operations to a minimum. The caller can choose to regularly flush the file.
Could a seek destroy my previously written data if it's still buffered somewhere? The seek call uses some strategy internally and I can't follow that path. No idea what it's doing internally.
Do I need to call Flush() explicitly before any Seek()? Or does the FileStream know which data needs to go where?

"Can you provide some evidence for these "buffers" of BinaryWriter, please? I can't seem to find them." - I checked the code; you're right, my mistake - no buffers there, but: I maintain that BinaryWriter adds vanishingly little here. But yes, it is also unlikely be be causal. Any threading etc in play here?

Any threading? I hope not. I added lock guards to all places that use this code. And most data objects in my application are immutable.

I am intrigued, but I don't know that there's enough context here for me to make guesses what is wrong. But this is one of my "areas" (I do a lot of data comms, serialization, and distributed systems stuff at MSFT). If adding more flushes fixes it: do that? But I would expect setting the position to flush internally. As a side note, I'd be tempted to look at Span-T direct access over MMF here, since it is fixed size.

The problem is, the bugs occur only irregularly every few hours to days and I need to monitor manually. Making any changes and waiting is a very uncertain strategy. I created a test case that tries to behave the same, just faster, but it runs correctly. In the end, this is going to be an open-source project. It's just way to incomplete now to publish it. But would it help? – And what's that Span-T thing?

I fully understand the frustration of hard to report scenarios and data corruption. That is basically my life :p Very late evening here - will try to give an example of the other thing tomorrow; hard to know if it'll help without understanding the real problem, which I don't (and can't without more context, I suspect)

@MarcGravell Quick update: I found out that I was catching exceptions at one place but failed to log them. What was logged then has led me to finding that threading is indeed an issue here. Quick fixes reduce the now-visible error rate significantly, but I need to synchronise things more thoroughly.

k, give me a sec, let me see if I can do something...

here's a super-simple MMF example; note no manual access - we just blit the struct directly into/out-of the file, letting the OS worry about how to do that in terms of buffers; you can also get hold of the view contents as a raw Span<T>, but that takes a little more work due to having to manage the handle: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/747e87932083f3dccf693f0d205b5c5d - note that MMF is a complex area, but: it is also super powerful for large files accessed in fixed-sized chunks

note that you can't use things like string, but if you need fixed-sized text data: "fixed buffers" (of type char) or "inline arrays"

and here's a version using Span<T> and ref-returns; this makes it easier to work directly with values in the MMF region without needing MMF-specific APIs, since increasingly number of .NET APIs now work great with Span<T> and ref: https://gist.github.com/mgravell/f9c80d6e54f2588608fefec3f54c73b2; it also works better for large values - note the use of inPlace - that doesn't copy the value out - the use of ref here means that inPlace is a managed pointer on the stack, to the data; we don't need to copy the entire value on the stack to work with it
